# AFNetworking 2.0 AFHTTPSessionManager

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, afnetworking-2

When I use `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`, I can use the `HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest` method with `NSURLRequest` object.  With this object, I can configure the request object with http body in which I can put a xml file.

Now I try to use the newer `AFHTTPSessionManager`, I only can use the `GET`, `POST`, etc.  How I can put a xml file in the http request's body?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In AFNetworking 2, a new object called the "request serializer" is how you are supposed to create your request body.  There is no built-in serializer for posting XML.  You'll need to subclass `AFHTTPRequestSerializer`, and set it as your manager's request serializer, like so:

```
[AFHTTPSessionManager manager].requestSerializer = [YourXMLRequestSerializer serializer];
```

When you subclass AFHTTPRequestSerializer, you'll need to override `requestWithMethod:URLString:parameters:error:` to return an NSMutableURLRequest with your desired content.